# Update menu links based on the site URL

Tags: 8, navigation

I have URLs defined in links.menu.yml file as "route_parameters: {webform: 'abc'}", but I need to update webform value based on the page URL.
If URL has "/type1/" in it, keep webform: 'abc'
OR
If URL has "/type2/" in it, change the webform to webform: 'xyz'

please suggest.

Comment: Use the method getRouteParameters() in a menu link plugin. See for example this tutorial  https://www.axelerant.com/blog/adding-dynamic-values-menu-links-drupal

Answer (score 0):

so need to have a hook_form_alter
then if this is the webform id you need
see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AgetRouteParameters/9.2.x

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODUE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'XXX') {
    $prams = Drupal\Core\Url::getRouteParameters();
    if (!empty($prams)) {
      dump($prams);
      // set the value of the field here/
    }
  }
}
```